# Node.JS Low Level Tls HTTP Proxy Tunnel

Tags: node.js, http, https

### Introduction

I hope to issue raw https requests through a http proxy tunnel. I've had problems because of bad requests by which the server could not understand.

These raw https requests include first connecting to example.com in the proxy, and then posting data to it.

```
var http = require("http");
var tls = require("tls");

let proxyhost, proxyport;

http.request({
    host: proxyhost,
    port: proxyport,
    method: 'CONNECT',
    path: `www.example.com:443`,,
    headers
}).on('connect', (res, socket) => {
    if (res.statusCode === 200) {
        const conn = tls.connect({
            socket: socket,
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            servername: 'www.example.com'
        }, () => {
            conn.on('data', (data) => {
                console.log("chunk:", data.toString('ascii'));
            })
            const args = [
                'CONNECT www.example.com:443 HTTP/1.1',
                'Host: www.example.com:443',
                'Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive',
                '',
                'POST / HTTP/1.1',
                'Host: www.example.com',
                'accept-encoding: deflate, gzip, br',
                'accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                'content-type: application/text',
                'origin: https://www.example.com',
                'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9',
                'content-length: 10',
                'xxxxxxxxxx' // this is supposed to be the post body
            ];
            // conn.write("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nconnection: keep-alive\r\nhost: www.example.com\r\n\r\n", "ascii")
            conn.write(args.join("\r\n"));
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Could not connect to proxy!');
    }
}).end();
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.